# Redirecting when not viewed in frame

Tags: html, redirect

I have an wc.html and I have the index.html with the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My title</title>
    </head>
    <frameset rows="*">
        <frame src="wc.html">
    </frameset>
    <noframes></noframes>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

and I want that when the wc.html is viewed separately and not in the index, it would redirect to the index page.

How do I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: frames have been removed from [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#obsolete-elements).

Comment: why do you want to use frames??? See http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/website-frames/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if(window.parent.location.href==undefined){
   window.location="index.html";
}
```

Comment: frames have been removed from [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#obsolete-elements).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var location = window.location.href;
    if(location.indexOf('wc') != -1 || location == undefined){
        window.location.href = "index.html";
    }
```